# Incremental method to change the cells ID (Name)

Tags: excel

I'm trying to setup an excel sheet with different columns and in every column I need the single cells to have a specific ID so I can reach to those by code, the simpler one was to put for ex. "column name1" and incremental from there, do you know a method to make something like that instead of changing all the cells ID by hand?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c696E.png)

Like this one for example, but intead of having 'feature1' 'feature2' ecc written as text I need those in the cells IDs/Names

EDIT
[example of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkp5H.png)
Here I want to use a formula to automatically change the name of the table from "A26" to "step1", I tried to use command `="step"&ROW(A26)` but this only change the text of the cell instead of the name

Comment: Have you tried like this -- =`"Feature"&ROW(A1)` and filling down, shall give you what you need

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya do I need to take the command from the first "? and If yes do I need to put it inside the text of the cell and just drag down? And last thing, I imagine that the A1 is referred to the cell ID i'm working on

Comment: Lets assume, you want to enter in Cell A2, cell A1 is the header there enter the above formula, in cell A2 `="Feature"&ROW(A1)` and fill down or use the fill handle to drag down

Comment: `ROW(A1)` means 1, so on so forth, to learn more on `ROW` Function --> https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-row-function

Comment: does that work for you

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya for example I saw the first empty row for feature Is at position J26, I wrote the command ="Feature"&ROW(J26) but it goes on #NAME? error because it see some error in there, I'm trying to figure why but it seems that this formula doesn't already set up the cells Id

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, I am not able to understand you now, this is because if you enter this in a cell `="Feature "&ROW(J26)` it shall give you `Feature 26`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya That "feature 26" needs to become the new name of the cell formerly known as J26 to be more accessible, but It seems like excel doesn't recognize the ROW() command so it's not working

Comment: Could you show me an expected output, with what you have in the beginning and what you need at the end?

Comment: Please check in answers, what you need to do!

Answer (score 0):

Although I have shared above what `ROW` Function, does, still for a proper explanation I am sharing here

The `ROW` function returns the **row number** for a reference.

In our query, **ROW(J26)** returns **26**, since **J26** is the **twenty sixth row of the column J in the spreadsheet**. When no reference is provided, `ROW` returns the `row number` of the cell which contains the formula. So in the above query `ROW()` returns **26** which on subtracting with **25 shall give us 1 which is required**.

`ROW` function takes just one argument, called `reference`, which may be empty, a `cell reference`, or a `range`.

So the formula used in cell **J26**

```
=J$25&ROW()-25
```

And **Fill Down** and for the rest just press **CTRL R** and **fill down**!

[image: Excel ROW Function]

Comment: After some time I found a way out of this problem, but it seems like I couldn't make the purpose of the question clear, I was searching for something that goes to modify the **name** of the cells, **not** the text inside it, so picking your image for exaple you can see that the **cell name** of the selected one is still **J26**, and that's the exact thing I was trying to change

Comment: @sMuLe Sorry you want to change the name of the cell reference like J26 shall become STEP 1 like this right? for that you need to use defined name manager!